# Page based application animation in ios 3x, 4x

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to make an application for reading books with flip page animation like page based application. But as i know that page based application is only available in iOS 5 and later, so in older platforms (ios 3x & 4x) how can i make flip animation like page based application (such as ibooks). I know a open source named "leaves" that i can also make flip page animation but it seems not vivid. thanks for your helps!

Comment: Are you sure you even want to continue supporting iOS 3-4, a vast majority of users are on iOS 5.

Comment: Since Apple will only allow apps that support iOS 6 now you can't build apps for armv6 any more, which means that you will be forced to drop support for any thing lower that 4.3. Then you could just al well just drop support for iOS 4 in general. stick with 5 and 6.